# Как с помощью xmlhttprequest можно выводить подпункты только при нажатии?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

```
    <?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'test_db';
    $login = 'postgres';
    $pass = 'postgres';

    $conn = pg_connect("host=$host port=5432 dbname=$dbname user=$login password=$pass");
    if(!$conn) {
        echo "Ошибка подключения";
        exit;
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'>

<body>
    <b>Меню</b>
    <ul class="treeline">
        <li>
            <div class = "drop_">Пункты</div>
                <ul>
                    <li> 
                        <input type="button" onclick="#" value="1"> Пункт       
                    </li>
                        <ul>
                            <?php
                                $result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT nazvanie FROM punkti1");
                                if(!$conn) {
                                    echo "Ошибка запроса";
                                    exit;
                                }

                                while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){
                                    echo "<li>" . "$row[0]" . "<li>";

                                }
                            ?>                          
                        </ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="button" onclick="#" value="2"> Пункт
                    </li>
                    <ul>
                        <?php
                            $result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT nazvanie FROM punkti2");
                            if(!$conn) {
                                echo "Ошибка запроса";
                                exit;
                            }

                            while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){
                                echo "<li>" . "$row[0]" . "<li>";

                            }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: menu]

Comment: Так а сам `xmlhttprequest` где?